# Parse Value from repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">

<HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="sf_newsList">
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>  
<asp:Literal ID="Publication_Date" runat="server" Text="{0}" />
...
```

Ok so i have a date coming back from the source, i need to strip this date into day and month as it currently
comes back like "march 12 2012".

once parsed into a day and a month string i want to then pass it back into

```
<asp:Literal ID="Publication_Day" runat="server" Text="{0}" />
```

now ive tried some things such as

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    string newsdate = "";
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Literal ltDate = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("Publication_Date");
        newsdate = ltDate.Text;
        //do parse code
        Literal ltDay = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("Publication_Day");
        ltDay.Text = newsdate;
    }       
}
```

but when i step through the publication_date is only returning {0} as a string not the date.

i know the source is fine, as if i just put the date on the template is shows up on the front end.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of object you are binding on the repeater?

Comment: What is the value of `ltDate.Text` in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returnin `{0}` because it is on the `Text` property of Literal.

You could use the `DataBinder.Eval` to read the column of your DataSource from `e.Item.DateItem`. Since you know what is the column you want to read you could get the `DateTime` object direct from datasource, for sample:

```
// get the dateTime from datasource
DateTime datePublication = DateTime.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "DatePublicationColumn").ToString());

// show the day name
ltDay.Text = datePublication.ToString("dddd");
```

Where I add `DatePublicationColumn`, you specify the column.

Comment: ah so throw that into my IF statement inside my repeater method?

Comment: Yes, but remember, I do not know if your column is the `DatePublicationColumn`. make sure it is the right name and change if necessary.

Comment: yeh, thats a problem, this is code that is inside the sitefinity cms, im trying to change the layout of the news items, unfortunatly I do not know what table is being used.  have you used sitefinity before?

Comment: No, I do not know how to implement it using `sitefinity`, maybe using a debugger you can check.

Comment: yeh just did found the table, the column isnt a datefield, its a varchar called url, the date is actually inside there.... "/12-03-27/newsitemname"

Comment: Well, the code to read a column from datasource is it :), maybe your the problem could be in another level.

Comment: how would i get the day "27" and the month "march" from that string?